# How to make methods of Tkinter's class private?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

Here's the code of a window, using `tkinter` library and OOP. I want to make methods of class `App` private. But some of them, like method `destroy` in code below should be public

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # window settings
        self.title("Private Attributes")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)


root = App()  # create window
root.title("Public Attributes") # this shouldn't work

ttk.Label(root, text="Close this window").pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy).pack() # this should work

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't, at least not without violating the Liskov Substiution Principle. As an instance of `Tk` (via a subclass `App`), `root` must be assumed to have a `title` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something that doesn't expose one or more `Tk` methods, you should use composition rather than inheritance. For example,

```
 class App:
     def __init__(self):
         self._root = Tk()
         self._root.title("Private Attributes")
         self._root.resizable(width=False, height=True)

     def mainloop(self):
         return self._root.mainloop()


root = App()
root.title("Public Attributes")  # AttributeError
root.mainloop()  # OK
```

You'll need to decide if the ability to limit access to various `Tk` methods (remember, you can still access `self._root` directly, but the name suggests that you are responsible for any errors stemming from doing so) outweighs the amount of boilerplate you'll need to write to expose the methods you *do* want access to. (Reducing that boilerplate is beyond the scope of this answer.)